# how to add numbers from inputbox?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, for-loop, textbox

This is my code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    InputBox("Enter Amount Of Courses")
    InputBox("Enter Course Name")
    InputBox("Enter Course Price")
End Sub
```

How can i repeat

```
InputBox("Enter Course Name")   
InputBox("Enter Course Price")
```

the amount of times the code

```
InputBox("Enter Amount Of Courses")
```

tells me to? And then I want to add the course prices together to get a total amount and then display the total in a textbox? I also want to display the course name, course prices in another textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save amount of times in the variable and use `For Next` loop for asking another values

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim amountValue As String = InputBox("Enter Amount Of Courses")
    Dim amountOfCources As Int32
    If Int32.TryParse(amountValue, amountOfCources) = True Then
        For i As Int32 = 1 to amountOfCources
            InputBox("Enter Course Name")
            InputBox("Enter Course Price")
        Next
    End

End Sub
```

Comment: how can I display what I have said in "Enter Amount Of Courses", "Enter Course Name" and "Enter Course Price"?

Comment: You can use [DataGridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to show names and prices of given courses

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim num As Integer = InputBox("Enter Amount Of Courses")

    Do While num > 0
        InputBox("Enter Course Name")
        InputBox("Enter Course Price")
        num = num - 1
    Loop
```

This should do it. :)